# Is it possible to use T4MVC with Attribute routing (RoutePrefix/Route)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, t4mvc

Are attribute-based routes supported by T4MVC in some way?

I have applied a `RoutePrefixAttribute` to my MVC 5 controller and a `Route` attribute on my action.  T4MVC, as it stands, does not seem to provide routes based on these attributes.  The route that it provides is the convention-based routes of `/Area/Controller/Action.`

Folder structure is:

```
/
 Areas
     Ratio
        Controllers
             RatioSet
                 PresetGroupController.cs
        Views
             RatioSet
                 GroupDetails.cshtml
```

Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("Ratio/RatioSet/Preset/Group")]
public partial class PresetGroupController 
{
    [Route("Details")]
    public virtual ActionResult Details()
    {
        //.....

        return View(MVC.Ratio.RatioSet.Views.GroupDetails, model);
    }
}
```

Now, if I try the following:

```
return RedirectToAction(MVC.Ratio.PresetGroup.Details());
```

I get a 404 error, because the requested URL is:

```
<app_root>/Ratio/PresetGroup/Details
```

which is the "default" route, rather than the correct attribute-specified:

```
<app_root>/Ratio/RatioSet/Preset/Group/Details
```

So, does T4MVC only work with the convention-based routes, inferred from the folder structure, and not any routes that are specified via attributes?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem and ended up fixing it adding the RouteArea attribute to the Controller.

Something like this:

```
[RouteArea("Ratio")]
[RoutePrefix("Ratio/RatioSet/Preset/Group")]
public partial class PresetGroupController 
{
    [Route("Details")]
    public virtual ActionResult Details()
    {
        //.....
        return View(MVC.Ratio.RatioSet.Views.GroupDetails, model);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still of some interest to me.  Thanks, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the non-T4MVC equivalent is working? If so, what does that line look like?

Note that T4MVC really doesn't generate routes itself, but instead calls into standard MVC framework methods to do this. See section 1.1 in the [docs](https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/documentation).

My guess is that you're running into an issue that is unrelated to T4MVC. e.g. see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466960/attribute-routing-not-working-in-areas) where the problem is the order of registration calls.