# Custom Routing in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

In my MVC5 application I have several `Actions` inside a `Controller`.

**Library** is `Area`, **Books** is the name of `Controller` and **AddBook** is `Action` name.

And following is the default URL pattern for that:

```
http//localhost/Library/Books/AddBook
```

But I want the URL to be something like:

```
http//localhost/Library/Books/Add-Book
```

or

```
http//localhost/Library/Books/Add/Book
```

but the `Action` name should be the same **AddBook** in the `Controller`.

I don't want to use the `Action` in the URL.

Plesae guide me how can I make this happen.

Thanks,

Comment: Look up [attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx), this is probably the easiest for you to get your head round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute routing for that:

```
[Route("Books/Add-book")]
public ActionResult AddBook()
{
}
```

See [Attribute Routing not working in areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466960/attribute-routing-not-working-in-areas) to get that to work with areas.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with tha annotation `[ActionName("action")]`

in your case :

```
[ActionName("add-book")]
public ActionResult AddBook()
{
}
```