# How to use Route attribute while working with areas in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am working on a project which is having some areas defined in it. I want to use Route attribute to do routing in my project. So I used `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` in my `route.config` file. The following is my `route.config` file.

```
public class RouteConfig
{

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Shopper.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

After that I am having two areas in my project like `productarea` and `productcategoryarea`. I have `global.asax` file as below.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {

           // AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        }
    }
```

I want to give routes to some of the methods from `productcategoryarea` and `productarea`. but when i applies `Route("productcategories")` on one of methods of `productcategoryarea` it will show me 404 error.

This is my `productcategoryregistration.cs` file from `productcategoryarea`

```
 public class ProductCategoryAreaAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "ProductCategoryArea";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "ProductCategoryArea_default",
                "ProductCategoryArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {controller="ProductCategory", action = "ListOfProductCategory", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

This is my method on which i want to provide route attribute.

```
[Route("productcategories")]
        public ActionResult ListOfProductCategory(ProductCategoryManager productcategorymanager, int page = 1, int pageSize = 4)
        {
            if (Session["UserName"].ToString() != null)
            {
                if (Session["UserName"].ToString() == "admin")
                {
                    //returning list of product category
                    List<ProductCategory> listproductcategories = db.ProductCategories.ToList();
                    PagedList<ProductCategory> model = new PagedList<ProductCategory>(listproductcategories, page, pageSize);
                    return View(model);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

So please help me to get out of it.

Comment: Have you explicitly set `RouteArea` attribute in controller class? There you may want to add area attribute like `area = "ProductCategoryArea"`. Also you may require `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` method to be uncommented.

Comment: see following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466960/attribute-routing-not-working-in-areas

Comment: After uncommenting the AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() it was giving me an error called "Routing for product categories are repeated.". I had also done with the area="productcategoryarea" but its not working.