# MVC 5 Multiple Routes to Same Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In our `RouteConfig.cs` file we have the following default route:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Original", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "Path.To.Controllers" }
            );
```

Our application is split into several different "Areas". This particular route works perfectly fine.

We were asked to change one of our URLs, however the underlying codebase is the same. In an effort to avoid breaking existing links out there I'd like to setup my controller to support two different routes:

Here's an example of what the original URL looks like:

`website.com/MyArea/Original`

With the aforementioned "Default" route in place, this will be directed to the `OriginalController` in the `MyArea` Area, and will hit the default `Index` action since none was specified.

My goal is to setup another URL that will also direct itself to the `OriginalController`. That is,

`website.com/MyArea/Other`

Should route to the `OriginalController` in the `MyArea` Area, and hit the default `Index` action.

I've added the following to the `RouteConfig.cs` file:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Other",
                url: "Other/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Original", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "Path.To.Controllers" }
            );
```

What I'm finding is that the `Default` route config is *always* used in favor of the `Other` route config, which causes a binding issue stating "`OtherController` could not be found". I suspect this is because they have a very similar signature in the `url` template, but I'm not entirely sure how to get around that.

I'm aware that there's a `Route` attribute also, which I'm not opposed to using. I unfortunately was unsuccessful in getting that setup correctly though.

After researching and attempting several different combinations I still can't get both URLs to route to one controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what went wrong with `Route` attribute? it should work just fine if you will specify full url (e. g. for test purpose).

Comment: here is the standard order of routing precedence:
    Check the Order property (if available).
    Order all routes without an explicit Order attribute as follows:
        Literal segments.
        Route parameters with constraints.
        Route parameters without constraints.
        Wildcard parameter segments with constraints.
        Wildcard parameter segments without constraints.
    As a tie-breaker, order the routes via a case-insensitive string comparison.
Check out his article http://rion.io/2015/11/13/understanding-routing-precedence-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Thanks @Michael, that resource was very helpful in identifying how routes are analyzed. You also made me re-think the Route attributes, so I gave it another go. I was able to get it working this time around and posted my solution below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the expected result using `RouteAttribute` on the controller itself (thank you @Michael for the resources and making me take another look at the RouteAttribute), rather than conventional `MapConfig` routing. As I described in my question above, I was having difficulties when attempting the `Route` approach in that I was receiving 404 errors stating the "resource could not be found".

It turns out the above errors were due to the fact that my attribute routing wasn't being wired up in the correct order, which forced the conventional route to be used (e.g. Default MapConfig) over my Route attributes.

I stumbled upon [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466960/attribute-routing-not-working-in-areas) which states:

> You are probably combining convention based routing with attribute
>   routing, and you should register your areas after you map the
>   attribute routes.
>
> The line
>
> `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` should be called AFTER this line:
>
> `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`

When working with Areas, you must register those areas after you register the attribute routing. I was originally registering my areas in the `Application_Start` method of `Globas.asax.cs`, which is called before the `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes`. I moved this registration to right below my `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` call in the `RouteConfig.cs` file, which allowed the following route attribute on the controller to work as expected:

```
[RouteArea("MyArea")]
[Route("Original/{action=index}", Order = 1)]
[Route("Other/{action=index}", Order = 0)]
public class OriginalController : Controller {
    ...
    ...
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index() { ... }
}
```

With the above in place, I can now navigate to either of the below URLs which will properly route to the "Index" action of my `OriginalController`:

`website.com/MyArea/Original`

`website.com/MyArea/Other`

This works. However, I do have another action defined that choked up the attribute routing and caused the conventional Default route (defined via the MapConfig function) to be used. My action signature:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int id) {
    ...
}
```

The route to this action is: `website.com/MyArea/Original/Details/123`, which also satisfies the default conventional route of `{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

The way around this was to go a step further with defining route attributes at the action level:

```
[Route("Original/Details/{id:int}")]
[Route("Other/Details/{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int id) {
    ...
}
```

Now my Route Attributes are found first, *then* the conventional route is used.